# GTM - Creating a list of products in GTM - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

Ahoy,

i am using built in gtm plugin on wordpress/woocomerce and it gets the following content:

```
cartContent: {
    totals: {
      applied_coupons: [],
      discount_total: 0,
      subtotal: "2844.715447",
      total: "2844.715447"
    },
    items: [
      {
        id: "K-GG-V4-S",
        name: "Grill Gazowy Koler Relish v4 5 palników 17,2kW",
        sku: "K-GG-V4-S",
        category: "Grille Gazowe",
        price: 3499,
        stocklevel: 41,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: "5900000002453",
        name: "Fartuch Koler",
        sku: "5900000002453",
        category: "Wszystkie produkty",
        price: 0,
        stocklevel: null,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: "6600006666664",
        name: "Pokrowiec + wąż i reduktor",
        sku: "6600006666664",
        category: "Wszystkie produkty",
        price: 0,
        stocklevel: null,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  },
```

but I have to implement the entire content of the basket into something that is to change dynamically depending on the number of products:

```
<script>
    wph('track', 'AddToCart', {
        content_type:  'category',
        contents: [{
            id:  'PRODUKT_ID1',
            name:  'NAZWA_PRODUKTU1',
                        category: 'KATEGORIA_PRODUKTU1',
            ean:  'PRODUKT_EAN_ID1',
            price:  20.15,
            in_stock:  true
                        quantity: 1
                        weight : 'WAGA PRODUKTU'
            }, {
            id:  'PRODUKT_ID2',
            name:  'NAZWA_PRODUKTU2',
                        category: 'KATEGORIA_PRODUKTU2',
            ean:  'PRODUKT_EAN_ID2',
            price:  20.15,
            in_stock:  true
                        quantity: 1
                        weight : 'WAGA PRODUKTU'
            }]
    })
</script>
```

How can I do this in GTM? I must admit that it was a bit too much for me, because I usually didn't need the entire basket.

Comment: Do you want to know how to get your code into GTM? Or do you want to know how to get the dynamic values from woocommerce? Or do you want to know how to send Enhanced Ecommerce hits to GA?

Comment: @Cthulchu I need the first option. All variables i have in dataLayer, but i have problems with implements code into GTM - mainly loops with products.

Comment: what have you tried doing in GTM to what avail actually. Or do you want to hear something like: "make a datalayer variable type of a variable in GTM for each actual DL field that you're setting, then make a custom HTML tag in which you reference your DL variables with {{varName}}"

Comment: @Cthulchu extracting variables and assigning them is not a problem. the problem is working on objects and loops because it just crashes to me. I am a beginner, so I do it all from tutorials. 
i can't make a list of products and this is what i strive for.